# Mysql FROM_UNIXTIME converts 1st march as 28th February

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

I am trying to create a event calendar . All dates are working fine but 1st of any month became the last of previous month. Here is my Mysql query -

Query 1-

```
$sql = "select  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date), '%Y') as mnth,
                DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date), '%M') as yr 
        from ".EVENT." 
        GROUP BY (DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date), '%M %Y')) 
        ORDER BY(post_date) ASC limit $offset ,$limit";
```

In loop -

```
$loop="SELECT * 
       FROM ".EVENT." 
       WHERE event_status='1' 
             AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date), '%Y')=".$result['mnth']." 
             AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date), '%M')='".$result['yr']."' 
      ORDER BY(post_date) ASC" ;
```

Comment: You should not use `FROM_UNIXTIME` on interally stored timestamp columns. MySQL knows how to deal with them. `FROM_TIMESTAMP` may have server timezone related issues.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. how can i change server timezone ??

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. Does removing the `FROM_UNIXTIME` help with the problem at all?

Comment: Actually i stored the datetime from php code by using strtotime . will it be a issue ?

Comment: Well `strtotime` returns seconds elapsed since 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC (so no timezone issues there) however it assumes the input matches the default PHP timezone (not server time) so you need to be careful when calling it.

Comment: When in doubt use [`date_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) and set it to UTC.

Comment: Sorry for let reply . i change the default time zone to UTC but still have the same issue .

Comment: Thanks, the root of all issue is mysql time zome it is set as MST and i stored time as UTC . Again thank you very much . for assisting .

Answer (score 0):

By checking the mysql set timezone i find that it is set in MST and I stored all date as UTC format . for solving this issue i just convert my default time zone UTC to MST and it solve my issue .